# Using scss/sass trailing ampersand to target one level back

Tags: sass

I have two types of circles, one inside of `.poi.licensed` and one inside of `.poi.unlicensed`. I am trying to make it so that the `.circle` inside of `.poi.unlicensed` has a `$tangerine` border instead of `$turqoise`. How can I used the trailing amerpsand to do so in this situation. Keep in mind that there is a lot of other scss that I am excluding that is unrelated, so it has to stay in this general structure.

I was trying something along the lines of the following, but it compiles to `.unlicensed #licensed-v-unlicensed .poi .circle {}`

```
$turqoise: #40e8e3;
$tangerine: #ffa975;
#licensed-v-unlicensed {
    .poi {
        .circle {
            border: 5px solid transparentize($turqoise, 0.1);
            .unlicensed & {
                border: 5px solid transparentize($tangerine, 0.1);
            }
            @include breakpoint(medium up) {
                border-width: 10px;
            }
            border-radius: 50%;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: relative;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I read your first comment to mean that you are trying to achieve .poi.licensed.circle and .poi.unlicensed.circle, is that correct?

Comment: Not exactly. `.poi.licensed .circle` and `.poi.unlicensed .circle`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a trick I found on this [blog](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/), which was to use `@at-root` in order to start at the root and target the `.unlicensed` class. It's a lot more work than I had hoped to do, but the only solution discovered thus far.

```
$turqoise: #40e8e3;
$tangerine: #ffa975;
#licensed-v-unlicensed {
    .poi {
        .circle {
            border: 5px solid transparentize($turqoise, 0.1);
            @at-root #licensed-v-unlicensed .poi.unlicensed .circle {
                border: 5px solid transparentize($tangerine, 0.1);
            }
            @include breakpoint(medium up) {
                border-width: 10px;
            }
            border-radius: 50%;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: relative;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    }
}
```